# Create an xml document from InputStream

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Create an xml document from InputStream which contains xml data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xydev

Use this Xmlserializer

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer ();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter ();

            serializer.setOutput (writer);
            serializer.startDocument ("UTF-8", true);
            serializer.startTag ("", "xmlresponse");
            serializer.startTag ("", "employee");
             serializer.attribute ("", "id", "1456");
            serializer.endTag ("", "employee");
.....
```

I hope you will dig out rest

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean, but check the docs for [DocumentBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html).